# mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError:1064

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'am trying to fill data into a database from a cvs file. I got this 1064 error,but I can't find where is the bug.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "code.py", line 252, in 
>               fill_patient()
>             File "code.py", line 169, in fill_patient
>               cur.execute(sql,data)
>             File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
>               self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>             File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
>               raise errorclass, errorvalue
>           _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Y1_99341','case','Solo, Han','Tatooine St-Wookie Clinic',0,26,37,0)' at line 1")

My code:

```
    def fill_genotype():
        con = connect()
        cur = con.cursor()

        with open("./data/genotype.csv",'rU') as f:
            header = ['SAMPLE_ID','PATIENT_ID','LOCATION','AFTER_TREAT','CONCENT','VOLUME','RIN','DATE_COLLECT','FREEZER_ID','BOX_ID','X','Y']
            reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=header)
                reader.next()

            for row in reader:

                cur.execute("INSERT INTO INVESTIGATOR VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(row['SAMPLE_ID'],row['PATIENT_ID'],row['LOCATION'],row['AFTER_TREAT'],row['CONCENT'],row['VOLUME'],row['RIN'],row['DATE_COLLECT'],row['FREEZER_ID'],row['BOX_ID'],row['X'],row['Y']))

        con.commit()
            con.close()
```

Comment: The `Y1_99341` has an extra quote, start there.

Comment: thanks a lot to edit the question for me and fast answer.
I don't know what to change actually, because  i wrote the same code   for every column. ps: row['SAMPLE_ID'], but the value of other column doesn't have extra quote.

Comment: I'm not sure of the issue, I'm not familiar with Python but from the error message that's where I'd start debugging (I ended up on the thread because it didn't have its language tagged).

Comment: You do not need reader.next(), you are just skipping that first row of data. DictReader returns a generator of dicts.